# What is the correct way to access shared variables inside `jest.mock`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to reuse a variable between multiple `jest.mock` calls in a same test file.

`jest.mock` calls are hoisted to the top by `babel-jest` so usually the variables outside the mock function scope are not allowed to be accessed. But the error message says:

> This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.

So If I prefix the variables with `mock`, I no longer receive the error but the values are all still set to `undefined` inside the mock. I don't understand what the error message means by "lazily required". Is it possible at all to share variables between `jest.mock` calls?

**Reproducable example:**

```js
const mockReusableValue = { x: 5 };

jest.mock('../someModule', () => {
  console.log(mockReusableValue); // undefined
  return {};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`babel-jest` will hoist the module mock on the top of the scope meaning you can define the mock-prefixed variable in the outer scope and reuse it in your module mock like this

**`test.js`**

```js
const mockData = 3;

describe('someModule`s someMethod returning mockData', () => {
  jest.mock('./someModule', () => ({
    someMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockData)
  }))
})
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/FickleDependableCoderesource)